# The designer view of Visual Studio 2013 RC2 doesn't display anything, how to fix this?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

When I code Silverlight app, in the designer view area still display the preview of objects i added, but in Windows Runtime app, the designer view doesn't display the  preview of these objects, just the border of the phone, nothing else. When I click object,the border of them still display, so what's the error and how to fix that?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I shared my project folder and it worked !